# html form validation | attribute required does not work anymore - except for type="email" - Whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm looking for hours on my code and tried every hint I found in the internet.

I have a form - As you nearly all fields are required.

But the only field which my browser (Chrome) really checks is the email-field.

The "required" of the other inputs is somehow ignored by my browser.

Code:

```
   <label class="radio"> <input type="radio" name="Assessment Type" id="optionsRadios1"     value="Daten-Qualität" checked="checked" /> Quick Assessment "Daten-Qualität" für 378€</label> 
   <label class="radio"> <input type="radio" name="Assessment Type" id="optionsRadios2" value="Einsparpotenziale" />Quick Assessment "Einkaufserfolg & Einsparpotenziale" 750€</label>
<br>
    <table>
       <tr>
           <td><input class="span3" type="text" name="Name" value="Ihr Name" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Ihr Name') {this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value='Ihr Name';}" placeholder="Ihr Name" required/></td>

           <td><input class="span3" type="text" name="Firma" value="Ihre Firma" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Ihre Firma') {this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value='Ihre Firma';}" placeholder="Ihre Firma" required/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>    
           <td>
              <input type="text" class="span3" name="Telefonnummer" value="Ihre Telefonnummer"  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Ihre Telefonnummer') {this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value='Ihre Telefonnummer';}" placeholder="Ihre Telefonnummer"/> 

              <input type="email" class="span3" name="E-Mail-Adresse" value="Ihre E-Mail-Adresse" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Ihre E-Mail-Adresse') {this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value='Ihre E-Mail-Adresse';}" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail-Adresse" required/>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" class="span3" name="Position" value="Ihre Position" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Ihre Position') {this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value='Ihre Position';}" placeholder="Ihre Position" required/> 

               <input type="text" class="span3" name="Abteilung" value="Ihre Abteilung" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Ihre Abteilung') {this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value='Ihre Abteilung';}" placeholder="Ihre Abteilung" required/></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-warning" value="Bestellung abschicken" />
```

What's wrong here?

Thank you for your ideas - Sabine

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is? Are you asking how to make the fields required? Are you asking how to validate the fields?

Comment: making them required while keeping the labels in the fields for all browsers. sorry, my question was not clear enough - I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are setting a value in each field if it is blank, in your `onblur()`.  Using a placeholder, I think your `onfocus()` and `onblur()` handlers are redundant, and causing the issue.

Comment: unfortunately "placeholder" does not work for many IE users.  But you are right ... seems like the "on blur" is causing this trouble...

Comment: Is there no way to put the labels inside the inputfields for all browsers AND making some fields required?

Comment: There are some jquery plugins that will help you do that, I think.  Since it is jquery it can be done in vanilla javascript.  I think one way to do it would be to do some manual validatrion, and make sure that the entered value does not equal your "placeholder" value.  And actually, in your case, since the placeholder gives no information that is not available via the labels, IMO, they are not necessary. It is my understanding that placeholders are for additional information, i.e. phone number formatting.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I think this would be a great solution for now!

Answer (score 1):

You have text in all the fields by default so they are valid, the reason why the `email` is different is because the text you have in that field is not a valid email.

Comment: Hm, I also thought about this, but the error message told me "Please fill in", not "Invalid email address" thats why I was not sure whats happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using just the `placeholder` attribute instead of the blur and focus Javascript for setting the default value. Those default values are being seen as valid by the browser's form validation.

Comment: placeholder alone did not work for many users... that's why we added the onfocus/onblur ... Is there any other way to put the labels in the input fields for all browsers?

Comment: Facebook used to do something with swapping a text input with the text "password" with a proper password field before they used placeholder. You might do something like that. Otherwise, you're back to manually validating your forms like the old days.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, do you have an example link?

Comment: I don't have a link because Facebook changed their approach. Basically, when the page loaded, the "password" field they had there was a text field with `value="Password"` This field had a focus event handler that hid it and revealed a true password field and placed focus in that field.